# Popup Window for StatusBar Item

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow, nsstatusbar

I'm building an Application and it needs to have a status bar item and a custom popup window, that popups when the status bar item is clicked.

I know how to set up a status bar item and a nsmenu for it, but I need a custom window rather than a nsmenu.

An example for what I'm looking for would be [Take Five](http://takefiveapp.com/mac) by the IconFactory

I really hope you have any ideas how I can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the following example project by Matt Gemmell:
[Using MAAttachedWindow with an NSStatusItem](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks just like what I'm looking for!